# Как при выполнении одной функции выполнить другие, а в случает возврата ею False вывести строку

Tags: python-3.x

вот сама функция

```
def IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):
if language in wikipedia.languages():
    return True
else:
    return False

def LanguageSetup(language):
if IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):
    wikipedia.set_lang(language)
else:
    return False
```

Вот здесь нужно вывести строку, в случае возврата функцией False
`

```
input = input().split(', ')
if IsLanguageExistInWikipedia() == False:
    print('no results')
else:
    LanguageSetup(input[-1])
    print(MaximumCountWordsOnPagesAndTitle(input[0:-1]))
    print(CreateChain(input[0:-1]))`
```

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема?

Comment: @Эникейщик не работает, я сам не понимаю почему, но не работает

Comment: Что означает "не работает"? Ну и вообще, для какого языка должен выводится результат? (Это подсказка такая)

Comment: @Эникейщик выводит кучу ошибок, но если убрать if  и else то все работает нормально, python3  для всех языков одна фраза, я не совсем понял подсказку, извини я очень долго уже сижу

Comment: Кучу ошибок надо читать. Они для того и выводятся, а не просто так.

Comment: @Эникейщик ошибки в ранфайлах

Comment: @Эникейщик line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script

Comment: @Эникейщик line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script

Comment: @Эникейщик  if IsLanguageExistInWikipedia() == False:
TypeError: IsLanguageExistInWikipedia() missing 1 required positional argument: 'language'

Comment: О чем говорит вам последняя ошибка? Я причём уже об этом намекал.

Comment: @Эникейщик отсутствует 1 обязательный позиционный аргумент... Сейчас попробую

Comment: Ну и?.. Разве это не прямое руководство к исправлению ошибки?

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил, появилась новая ошибка if not IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):
NameError: name 'language' is not defined

Comment: Рекомендую перечитать главу о функциях и как ими пользоваться. PS. И не называйте переменную input. После этого вы не сможете использовать функцию input().